# About using Multer(1.0.6) and Express to upload files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I want to use multer to upload images withe express from a form.

I find a [post](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/) about how to use multer to upload file, and trigger events to rename the file. However, I found it only works in old version (multer-0.1.6)

In the latest instruction in multer's [github](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), I think I have to use `disk storage engine` to upload the files with new name, however it does not works. Please give me some instructions, I tried this function whole day...

Moreover, I am not sure why `res.status(204).end();` is needed? I I don't add this line, the webpage will always lock when I click upload button...

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "FileUpload",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "multer": "^1.0.6",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**upload.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

var app = express();

app.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(204).end();
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("It's work");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     console.log("Dest");
     cb(null, 'uploads/')
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
   }
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

**index.html**

```
<form id        =  "uploadForm"
     enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
     action    =  "/uploadImage"
     method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Solution**
The reason for why my code can not run is the code's order...
The following order is right.

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');

var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("It's work");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     console.log("Dest");
     cb(null, 'uploads/')
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
   }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(204).end();
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: How to return error or success message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GitHub you can find this example and for me it's working:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

var app = express();

app.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(204).end();
});
```

Comment: @HardikMandankaa use callback

Comment: @HardikMandankaa there is a call back in app.post() method, which you can get error or success message